Kids with white hair kill older people in a small town
I have few memories about it, but I saw it around the 90s. I'm pretty sure it was a terror film.
There were some kids that kill older people in a small town. All of them had white hair and very blue eyes. There was also a kid whose mother didn't want to go with the evil kids.
I can remember a scene where older people wanted to burn the kids on a old church (or a wooden building).
I think they got special powers (I'm not sure about this one).

Sounds like a cross between one of the Children of the Corn and the remake of Village of the Damned

Village of the damned, the photo sounds very familiar to me,  thank you

@JamesMcLeod may be worth adding that in an answer so that it can be accepted.

Ive done, but people downvote the answer god knows why!

@Kek the answer is downvoted because the obvious answer is Children of the Corn. It's also a one line answer without a movie synopsis or description of why the answer fits the question. So half between wrong and quality issues.

The movie name is Village of the Damned(1995).

The quiet coastal town of Midwich in California's Marin County is
  invaded by an unseen force which leaves ten women mysteriously
  pregnant. Nine months later, the babies are born simultaneously on one
  night, though one is stillborn. At first, they all appear to be
  normal, but it does not take the parents long to realize that their
  children are anything but normal. As they grow older, the children are
  shown to have pale skin, white hair, fierce intellect and steely,
  cobalt eyes. However, they also do not appear to possess a conscience
  or personalities. The emotionless children display eerie psychic
  abilities and remarkable powers, which they use with deadly
  consequences, unleashing a reign of terror. When they actively use
  their mind-control powers, their irises or their entire eyes glow in
  different colors, mostly reddish-orange.


Thanks James Mcleod for the answer

One liner answer are not much good, kindly elaborate it a bit.

What the mod means is that you should expand/edit the answer with why it fits, like a screenshot of the white hair kids or a summary or synopsis of the movie, i.e. why it fits the description of the movie you gave.
